# C# automatically substitutes forward-slash with back-slash in path...why?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, slash

I have a textbox where I put the name of a file that contains the forward-slash character '/'
When I grab the text from the textbox the `'/'` is automatically replaced with `'\'` and it obviously can't find the file, for example:

I write C:\Users\Temp\my/file.txt
I get   C:\Users\Temp\my\file.txt

So, instead of opening "my/file.txt", it searches for a directory "my" which contains "file.txt"

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Just curious: On what O/S is `my/file.txt` a valid filename? (I.e. where the `/` isn't a directory specifier.)

Comment: `/` is invalid in NTFS file names. It's a directory specifier on Unix, Linux, MacOS. Where did you find a file named `my/file.txt` in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Windows (which I assume you are, given the paths in your example), then / is an invalid character for a filename:

[image: Example]

The easiest solution here would be to remove the slash from the filename as this is likely to cause further issues down the line.

Comment: I didn't think of that, thanks! I know it seems dumb but I have to make a mod to an app that already works and somehow that didn't came to my mind